# How to stop my non-terminating loop

Tags: java, exception

I created a class. I put `ab`, and `bd` in try statement. When I run this program and enter this or any other word, then in the output it keeps coming continuously without stopping "please enter a number", "Invalid denominator". It never stops.

```
public class ExceptionTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ab,bd,cde;
        ab=bd=cde=0;
        boolean infinite,number=false;
        do {
            try {
                ab = s.nextInt();
                bd = s.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception d) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
                number=false;
            }
            if (!number) { 

            }

            try { 
                cde = ab/bd;
                infinite = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Denominator");
                infinite=true;
            } finally { }
            if (!infinite)  { System.out.println(cde); }
        } while (cde!=100);
        s.close();          

        }

    }
```

Comment: before `System.out.println("Please enter a number");` add `System.out.println(e);` to see actual exception

Comment: @Lashane it would be better to use `e.printStacktrace()`.

Answer (score 0):

After you catch the exception you have to do something.  You can either allow for new inputs or you have to exit.  The do while will continue because you original input has not changed.